# Angular2 call one function component from another component

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

I have been searching for a while,on google, stackoverflow, but nothing, Angular2 seems to be DIY, not finish..
So i have login.component.ts, that contains the materialize modal template :

```
import { Directive, Component, Input, Output, OnInit, OnDestroy,  EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterializeModule,MaterializeAction } from 'angular2-materialize';

declare var $: any

@Component({
selector: "dialogs",
template: '
  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet" materialize="modal" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]" [materializeActions]="modalActions">
    <div class="modal-content">Modal Content</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" (click)="closeModal()">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
'
})
export class Dialogs implements OnInit {
  @Output() modalActions = new EventEmitter<string|MaterializeAction>();

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  openModal() {
   this.modalActions.emit({action:"modal",params:['open']});
  }
   closeModal() {
   this.modalActions.emit({action:"modal",params:['close']});
  }

}
```

And my header.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core"
import { LoginComponent  } from '../login/login.component';
import { Dialogs } from '../login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'headerCustom',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
  template:
          `
    <nav class="navbar-material light-blue lighten-1"  role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
    <img src="./images/logo.png" />
    </a>
    <a materialize="sideNav" href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    <li>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" (modalActions)="openModal()">Open Modal Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    <li>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" (modalActions)="openModal()">Open Modal Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>`
    })
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

    }
```

I want just simple actions, when i click on the buttons header, that'll open the modal? Why i can't call the function of login component?

I have try many code like :

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" (click)="modalActions.openModal()">Open Modal Login</a>
```

But nothing.

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (relatively) easy way that a component can get a hold of another component's methods and properties is to use a **local variable**.

However, it does require that the component calling the methods is a **direct parent** of the component containing the methods.

In your case, if the `Dialogs` component is a child of the `HeaderComponent` component, your code would look like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'headerCustom',
  template: `
    <!-- markup -->
    <button (click)="modal.openModal()">Open</button>
    <!-- markup -->
    <dialogs #modal></dialogs>
    <!-- markup -->
  `
})
export class HeaderComponent { }
```

Note the local variable `#modal` on the child component, which the parent can use to access its methods (`modal.openModal()`).

You didn't say how you structured your component tree, so it might not work in your case.

See [official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#parent-to-child-local-var).

Comment: Your'r GREAT :), it's so simple in fact, that's work well !!!! Thanks you very much !!

Answer (score 2):

**Call One Component Function From Another Component - Angular 2**

**Component A TS File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestService , RoleService } from '../../services/index';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.css']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  loading = false;
  constructor(private router: Router,
    private roleService : RoleService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
  userDetails = [];
  viewDetailsUsers(id){
    this.loading = true;
    this.roleService.viewUser(id)
    .subscribe(
        data => { 
            this.userDetails = data.result[0];
            this.loading = false;
        },
        error => {     
          console.log('error');
        });
  }
}
```

**Component B HTML File**

```
<div class="partImage">         
     <button type="button" class=" details" (click)=modalPop.viewDetailsUsers(item.id) data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModel">Details</button>
</div>
<app-user-details #modalPop></app-user-details>
```

**Compenent A HTML File**

```
<div id="userModel" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" [hidden]="loading">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">User Detail</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">       
        <div [hidden]=isHide class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="{{APIURL}}{{userDetails.photo_path}}{{userDetails.photo}}" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```